Python: detect regularly disconnecting faulty USB device and reinitialize instance
I have a USB device that sometimes sends serial data through USB port. Issue is that the device is faulty and sometimes for no reason it disconnects and connects again to PC. Not too large of an issue, but in these cases I need to reinitialize serial.Serial(port) instance, which is a little bit annoying. The device does not have any commands that could receive from me where I could verify that it is connected. I could write something that would launch a thread where it regularly monitors the device or something like that, but it is a little bit tedious, because the device is used with Windows and Linux PCs, I would need to take into consideration any edge cases and etc., which is quite annoying and tedious work.
Are there any solutions for this that already exist, where I could possibly attach a callback that would handle disconnect/connect event or somewhat similar workaround? I am looking for solution for both Windows and Linux (at the very least for Windows). Buying a new device is not a solution.
